# Shortcut for tab key in git to select particular directory

Tags: git, keyboard-shortcuts

I googled it before asking but seems my word selection for search is not appropriate :(

In Windows Command prompt whenever we want to select a sub directory we use

cd and TAB key press and all projects(sub directories) shown one by one, But in GIT it is not.

EX-

```
C:/Sites>cd aTHEN tab key press to display sub directories one by one
```

Some of my projects(sub directory) is having long names, so its always be hard for me to type the full name...so is there any key short cut like this in git just let me know then.

Comment: Instead of down voting, it would be better to add comment for doing this so

Comment: Are you asking how tab completion works in msysgit shell (which I assume you are using under windows)?  Try htting tab twice to see the list of all matching files ... msysgit tab completion is different to cmd.exe, you need to provide a unique pattern before it will conplete the word.  Non-unique patterns will do partial completion.  Or are you saying Windows' standard tab completion doesn't work for your git repos (it does for me).

Comment: @Gavin what I was asking is - when I open my git bash and want to go in sub directory..under windows I type cd a and press TAB key then the folder name starting with a comes on TAB ke press..but when I do the same in git its not working ..Like from C/sites/ I want to go to Check directory..then writing cd C and pressing TAB key wont worrk in git bash

Comment: In your C/sites directory, are there any other directories starting with the letter C?  If there are, bash won't autocomplete to the first in the list (it works differently to cmd.exe).  If you hit tab twice it should show you the list of directories matching what you've already typed so in your case it should show the list of directories beginning with C.

Comment: @Gavin yes I have other folders starting with C (like cat, cold etc just random) So can i take it as a grant that no such short cut key exists in git bash ?

Comment: Well, tab completion does exist, it just works differently to cmd.exe ... if you type `cd ca` and hit tab it would complete to cat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tab completion works differently in msysgit to cmd.exe

cmd.exe cycles through the completed directory/file names at each press of the tab key.

msysgit completes as far as it can according to the pattern already typed but if there are multiple directories matching that pattern, you need to type more to allow it to complete.

For example if your directory structure is:-

```
cat/
check/
cold/
dummydir/
```

Then typing `cd c` and hitting tab will do nothing (because three directories match).  Hitting tab a second time will display the matching directories (`cat, check, cold`).  Adding `h` to your command, to give `cd ch` and hitting tab will result in your command completing to `cd check`.

You can also use * to allow completion using the middle/end of filenames, e.g. `cd *k` would also complete to `cd check` in the example above.

Comment: perfect man..this is exactly what i want :) +1 and green tick :)